# How to force add line break in JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, text

I have a react app that fetches data from an API. The data fetched is a string.

One example of such a string is,

```
TicTacToe\n
This is a simple tic-tac-toe game.\n
The player plays against an AI, which uses minimax algorithm to find the best logical move.\n
The player starts with 'X' and the AI plays 'O'.\n
It's probably impossible to win this game.
```

As there are `\n`, I naturally hoped it would add new line to html.

This is html,

```html
<section className="intro">{d.about && d.about}</section>
```

where `d.about` contains the string with `\n` characters.

But the html is simply displayed as,

```
TicTacToe This is a simple tic-tac-toe game. The player plays against an AI, which uses minimax algorithm to find the best logical move. The player starts with 'X' and the AI plays 'O'. It's probably impossible to win this game.
```

How to add line breaks? Do I need the replace every `\n` with `<br />` after fetching from api? Will that work?

Comment: Sounds like you know what to do :) -- also look into `<pre>` and `<textarea>` as methods to utilize the text with `\n`

Comment: You can use <br/> or you can put the texts into an array, map them and do ```display: flex; flex-direction: column``` to the parent element. just a suggestion.

Comment: replace the \n with a br tag and see if it works... :)

Comment: if you can query the element by id or classname and then set innerText to the needed string, it should work. innerText should respect the '\n' character as I remember (yep, it should, tried on codepen: https://codepen.io/Sartymov/pen/dyvvoGZ?editors=1111)

Comment: @Kinglish actually I was just confused whether I must use a markdown library instead. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const strs = str.split('\n').filter(s => s);

return <div>
   {strs.map(e => <>{e}<br/></>)}
</div>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this by replacing all `\n` with `<br />` and You can bind to dom directly using **`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`** as per your requirement.

```
export default function App() {
  let str = `TicTacToe\n
  This is a simple tic-tac-toe game.\n
  The player plays against an AI, which uses minimax algorithm to find the best logical move.\n
  The player starts with 'X' and the AI plays 'O'.\n
  It's probably impossible to win this game.`;
  let updated = str.replaceAll("\n", "<br />");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: updated }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-lalande-gmyrg?file=/src/App.js:24-502)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to replacing the new lines with `<br/>` tags, you can use CSS to adjust how whitespace is rendered.

```js
const text = `TicTacToe\n
This is a simple tic-tac-toe game.\n
The player plays against an AI, which uses minimax algorithm to find the best logical move.\n
The player starts with 'X' and the AI plays 'O'.\n
It's probably impossible to win this game.`;

document.querySelector(".intro").innerText = text;
```

```css
.intro {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<section class="intro"></section>
```